# Can I see what I earned a secret hat for?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

I have earned a nice secret hat, but it has no explanation.

Is there any way to see how and why I earned it?

Comment: Your Chameleon hat seems to be for linking to a new stack or updating your profile. Your Warm Welcome hat seems to be for upvoting a new user

Comment: No, that's why it's secret.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a [Meta.se thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats) tracking the Winter Bash 2014 secret hats.

If your hat is there, then it should tell you what it (probably) means. If not, you could join the discussion there to try to work out what it means.

Comment: Or you can do what the people on that thread do, and try to reverse engineer :)